# Does the laplacian operator work on time as well as spacial variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I am currently working on a diffusion problem involving partial differential equations and am a bit confused about how the Laplacian (Laplace?) operator works on different independent variables such as time and space. Here is a picture of the question: [PDE Problem involving space and time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9mzC.jpg).

Now what I initially tried to do was expand out the laplace term into a second derivative in x and a second derivative in time. However, in the solutions which are provided in the following picture, they do not expand out a second derivative in time and I am confused as to why they would only do it in x. [Solution to PDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmsV9.jpg). Does the laplace operator only work on spacial variables then? Thank you for your help.

Note the method being used to solve the problem is a separation of variables.

Comment: The adjectival analogue of *spacial* is *temporal*, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when people write a Laplacian when there is a clear "time" variable and "space" variable(s), the Laplacian only hits the space variables. Sometimes people will explicitly write $\Delta_x$ or $\nabla^2_x$ to denote this, but usually it's clear from context. Here for instance they are talking about diffusion which definitely does not have a second time derivative involved.

Comment: Would there ever be a case where the second derivative in time was involved in a problem? Is that possible or even physically meaningful to talk about the second derivative in time?

Comment: You may be interested in studying $$\Delta u = u_{tt}$$, yes. This is the wave equation.

Comment: @AndrewSchroeder sure it's physically meaningful, this is acceleration!

Comment: Oh rip me lol, didn't even come to mind aha